# Conditional palette (or colour set) for the same SSRS 2008 chart

Tags: reporting-services, charts, colors, ssrs-2008

I need several series of pie chart in SSRS report to appear in grey scale, depending on Boolean value specified in data set, and have absolutely no idea how to approach this except hardcoding all colours. Some background information placed below.

Source data set looks like this:

[image: Stage CHAR(50), Estimated INT, Active BIT]

I need those sectors in pie chart that represent active stages (Active = 1) to be coloured automatically according to current palette, and those that are inactive - to appear in grey scale.  Of course, number of different inactive stages varies depending on parameters and report running time, but it is known and can be used for generation of grey scale colour data set.

Will be very grateful for any hints.

Answer (score 1):

How About in the series colour property using an expression such as

=iiF(Fields!Active.Value = 0, "LightGrey","Automatic")

Instead of using Active you could use Stage and nested IIF to give you your grey scale by choosing a different shade of grey for each of those items that are considered inactive.

You can create expressions to determine the palette at chart level but your issue here is chart comes before chart data.

Comment: That's pretty simple, but what I am talking about is greyscale _palette_, not just one colour. Inactive stages should appear in different greys, not just "light grey".

Comment: To any passersby: If you use this solution and need more that just a few colors, do yourself a favor and use a Switch statement for this. It will be much less of a headache than nested IIF.